# Error message not passed in Amplify.js request

Tags: amplifyjs

I have this code that uses amplify.js:

```
amplify.request.define('data', 'ajax', {
        url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST"
    });

amplify.request({
        resourceId: 'data',
        success: function(p1, p2, p3) {
            debugger;
        },
        error: function(p1, p2, p3) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
```

The problem is that is server reports error, then the in the error callback, the p1 is null, p2 is 'error' and p3 is undefined.

The similar jQuery.ajax fills these parameters correctly.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        success: function(p1, p2, p3) {
            debugger;
        },
        error: function(p1, p2, p3) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
```

Am I missing Amplify.js configuration to make this work?

Comment: Is the content type being set correctly?  ASMX is quite strict in terms of what it expects and will fail otherwise.  Try `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.  You also might want to check the data property is being sent correctly.  I think it needs to have an empty object sent if you aren't sending anything e.g. `"{}"` and data must be a JSON serialised string rather than a data object.

Answer (score 1):

Following this link

[Amplify Support Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/amplifyjs/JeuvAIr3_mg)

looks like parsing error body is not supported by default. I will have to write my own decoder for this.

Answer (score 0):

By default amplify is using Jsend decoder that you can replace with your own.
Here's my simple decoder that passes response body JSON object to both success and error callbacks:

```
amplify.request.decoders._default = function( data, status, ampXHR, success, error ) {

    if (status === "success") {
        success(data);
    } else {
        error(JSON.parse(ampXHR.responseText));
    }

}
```

PS. Before doing it, consider adjusting your api responses to the jsend conventions, read more here: http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend